# meaning of & in C++

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I am bit confused about a expression I found in some C++ code:

```
if (m & 1)
pmm=-pmm;
```

I am not a C/C++ coder, so Google gives me two things:

1. & is bitwise AND
2. `if` syntax is `if (condition) statement`

So, how does the above statement work? 
Should I not require a `if ((m & 1)==0)`?

Comment: What is the type of `m`?

Comment: It is the same as if(!(m % 2)) the c doesn't care what is really in "if" condition, it will be casted to the boolean type and casting will be false when data is 0, true otherwise.

Comment: @cerkiewny - no it isn't. If `m == 2` they evaluate differently.

Comment: @DavidM I was typing faster than thinking, corrected the error.

Comment: No, what you have is still wrong. You have inverted the condition. Correct that the test is effectively oddness/evenness, just the wrong way round.

Comment: Please read an introductory book on C programming!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to the more technical explanations, a simpler way of viewing `if (m & 1)` is that is tests whether `m` is *odd* (i.e. not an exact multiple of 2):

```
if (m & 1)
    // m is odd (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ...) - do something
else
    // m is even (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ...) - do something else
```

Answer (score 2):

**m** will be represented in memory as a binary number, in other words: a series of bits.
The value **1** will also be represented as a series of bits.

For example (I have chosen 8 bit length for simplicity):

```
m = 00101101
1 = 00000001
```

Performing a bitwise operation on **m** will perform the operation you specify, in this case **&** (AND) on each bit at the same position on each binary number on either side of the **&** symbol.

*i.e. Bit 1 of result = Bit 1 of m & Bit 1 of the value 1.
Bit 2 of result = Bit 2 of m & Bit 2 of the value 1 etc...*

So for our example:

```
  00101101
& 00000001
 ---------
  00000001
```

Assuming **m** is an integer, the bitwise operation will return an integer. The **if** statement will check if the result is true, and since it is an integer it will be interpreted as true if non-zero.

The result is not zero hence it will return true in our example.

So:
By **AND**-ing an integer with 1 you will end up returning true in your code for odd numbers only, since bit 1 is always 1 for odd numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This is bitwise AND operator. m & 1 evaluates to 1 if bit 0 is set and every expression that is not 0 is **true** implicitly.

Following are equivalent expressions:

```
if ((m & 1) == 1) // bitwise AND is 1
if ((m & 1) != 0) // bitwise AND is NOT 0
if (m & 1)
```

However caution is required if testing more bits. For example m = 1:

`if (m & 3)` is `true` also, but the result is `1`. Better is `if ((m & 3) == 3)` in this case.

Comment: actually, (given that `m` is an unsigned int) `m & 1` evaluates to `1` if bit 1 is set, and 1 in turn converts to the boolean value `true` implicitly; if bit 1 of m is not set, then `m & 1` evaluates to `0`, which converts to `false`

Comment: While those two statements are functionally equivalent, they are not semantically equivalent. If you had `!= 0` rather than `== 1` that might make it clearer to the OP (IMHO)...

Comment: Your are both right. Explicit form like `if ((m & TEST) == TEST` is the better solution here. And yes of course `m` need to be an integer type.