# Why check negative number with "&1"

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Just ran into this question when I tried to refactor my code for a LeetCode problem. The problem is to compare if a positive integer is smaller than the absolute value of another integer. Here is how I did it:(I know there is an **abs()** function but prefer **NOT** to use it)

```
if(A < B || A+B < 0)
// do something
```

where **A** is a positive integer no exceeding 1000 and **B** can be any 32-bit integer. However, I saw other solutions which were faster than mine did something like this:

```
if(A<B || (A+B &1))
// do something
```

I submitted a second solution with the **ONLY** change being the condition statement. I was surprised to see a little improvement. I could not explain this to myself, why the second condition works and why it is faster.

Can anyone explain a little bit?

### Update

Thanks for the quick responses. But no, this is different than the AND bitwise manipulation question pasted in the comment. That was how I thought in the first place. "&1" should simply be checking if the integer is odd or even. And I also understand that the conventional way to use AND operation, is to compare the significant bit, which is done by something like:

```
if((A+B >> 31) &1)
```

Here is a link to the problem: [Target Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/description/).

Comment: `x&1` just tests the least significant bit. Can you post REAL code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [meaning of & in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694225/meaning-of-in-c)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit

Comment: Is the *"others whose performance is faster than mine"* wrote the exact same code as you, with only this change? I doubt that. Since the two conditions check different things.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As you can see, new users are downvoted nearly instantly and only few give valuable feedback. However, please post a runnable code that shows your performance issues. Most likely, the performance issue is not related to this particular piece of code

Comment: @MauriceRandomNumber, thanks for the welcoming. this is my first post and I might be too vague at beginning. I tried to add more detail clarified some of the expression.

Comment: As you can see in this example, these two statements are not equivalent for A a positive integer no exceeding 1000 and B any 32-bit integer: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##bcvdCoMgGAbgY72KjwZDGYF2WDKoOxFzQ7CvMD1aXbsrt8OO3h94zLLUxmt853xzaHwaLSg3rzFYPT0pdRhh0g4Zhw8l5@qZFLz79YHVsinjBawHBQNsG/SP4aiiCLLGsW3NnCIoBZWsziifxdEfcv9jVSg77V3yK9tcWUqCjSkgiI7uOX8B)

Comment: try putting a few sample numbers through `if(A<B || (A+B &1))` and you'll see that it doesn't work, maybe thats why you can't understand how it does work? `B&1` simply returns 1 if B is odd or 0 if B is even

Comment: For some reason that leetcode link doesn't load for me, and links are anyway subject to decaying and making the question incomprehensible. Please write the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the actual behaviour you require, _and_ show some sample inputs with the expected result, because none of the partial code shown matches your description.

Comment: Thank you all for the explanation. I now realize I was jumping to a conclusion too fast without careful consideration. And also thanks for the tool and guidelines you guys put up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, considering the problem described, your second algorithm simply is not correct:

Consider the values `A == 10`, `B == -12`, then the first test in the if-clause will naturally fail, but second one *as well* (although it should *not*), as `A + B` calculates to -2 with bit representation of all bits *but least significant* one being set (two's complement provided).

So before considering performance, you should very first consider *correctness* of your code!

If now considering performance, there actually can be a difference at all only if the underlying hardware requires a different number of CPU cycles for calculating the AND operation and comparisons – which I doubt on typical modern hardware... And even if there *was* a difference (then most likely comparison needs more cycles), the compiler might decide by itself to optimise `< 0` to `& 0x80000000` (32 bit integer provided) resulting in exactly the same machine code for both variants (assuming you fixed the error in the second variant!).

If you really discovered a minimal performance difference, there can be quite a lot of totally unrelated reasons that might have fooled you, such as the test system getting more active due to incoming network traffic, another user starting another task, ... right while running one or the other of your tests. If you want to get absolutely reliable results you need to test on a hermetically closed system such as a dedicated micro controller (and still results can be hardware and compiler specific as described above!).