# What is if(i | j) and if (i & j) doing in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and, bitwise-or

Hello after learning C++ for several months I decided to look at some CPA practice questions and the very first question threw me off with this code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
 int i = 1, j = 2;
 if(i > j && j > i)
     i++;
 if(i > j || j > i)
     j++;
 if(i | j)
     i++;
 if(i & j)
     j++;
 cout << i * j << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is what the third and fourth if statements are looking for because I have never seen that syntax before. Thank You!

Comment: The third is using a bitwise `or`. The fourth is using a bitwise `and`. See the *Bitwise Operators* section of [C++ operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/)

Comment: Half duplicate of [meaning of & in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18694225/364696).

Comment: Do the bitwise operation by hand.  If the result is zero, the condition is treated as `false`.  If the result is non-zero, the condition is treated as true.

Comment: not a duplicate of "Using bitwise operators for Booleans in C++", since the operands are `int` in this case

Answer (score 0):

THey are bitwise operators. `|` is bitwise or and `&` is bitwise and.